# Is there a way to do a lazy lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some HTML text like below.

```
                <div style="background:#e0dddd; color:#333399; font:9PT 'arial'; padding:10px; margin-left:-30px; ">
                    <div>
                        <strong>Some text here1 </strong><br />
                        2021-08-08                    </div>

                    <div><p>
    Some text here2</p>
</div>
                    <div class="download">
                        <a href="index.php?obj=notice_id=1734">View Detail ...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div style="background:#e2ecf4; color:#333399; font:9PT 'arial'; padding:10px; margin-left:-30px; ">
                    <div>
                        <strong>Some text 3</strong><br />
                        2021-08-06                    </div>

                    <div><p>
    Some BE text 4.</p>
</div>
                    <div class="download">
```

What I'm trying to capture is the following, basically, from the tag `<strong>` onwards to the line that has `BE` in it. It can be case insensitive.

```
Some text 3</strong><br />
                        2021-08-06                    </div>

                    <div><p>
    Some BE text 4.
```

I'm using `/(?<=<strong>)[\s\S]*?b[ _\/,]?e[\W][\s\S]*?(?=<)/gim` but it captures the following.

```
Some text here1 </strong><br />
                        2021-08-08                    </div>

                    <div><p>
    Some text here2</p>
</div>
                    <div class="download">
                        <a href="index.php?obj=notice_id=1734">View Detail ...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="background:#e2ecf4; color:#333399; font:9PT 'arial'; padding:10px; margin-left:-30px; ">
                    <div>
                        <strong>Some text 3</strong><br />
                        2021-08-06                    </div>

                    <div><p>
    Some BE text 4.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The cheapest way is probably to let greed consume initial part: [`[\S\s]*<strong>([\S\s]*?BE)`](https://regex101.com/r/bKCc5N/1)

Comment: @bobble-bubble, That won't work because I have multiple such div, not only these two.

Comment: More costly:  Use a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) [like this](https://regex101.com/r/GOJDvV/2) or [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/GOJDvV/1) (faster) to not skip over another `<strong>`.

Comment: Your question looks like an XY problem. For what goal are you trying to do that? Also, the fact you want to capture a part of html without balanced tags around is particularly strange.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte,
I'm trying to retrieve information out of it. I do not need the tags for that, only the text around it. And it is not an XY problem. bobblebubble clearly got it.

Comment: If you only want to catch the text why you don't try to use the DOM?

Comment: Because I'm not a web developer. I know what DOM is but not much. So I'm trying regex.

Comment: And you use javascript from an html page or from nodeJS?

Comment: I'm currently running from an html but I'll eventually only use the JavaScript on my phone with Tasker.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a DOM based solution to iterate over the div elements (at the root level). Then a simple test on the inner text suffices to get the good one:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(`<div id="root">${yourhtml}</div>`, 'text/html');
doc.querySelectorAll('#root > div').forEach(function(el) {
    let text = el.innerText;
    if ( /\bb[^ ,_\/]?e\b/i.test(text) )
        console.log(text); // display in your browser console
});
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: @FrankShrestha: I don't know Tasker, but I have read somewhere that some versions don't support `let` and `const` keywords. In this case, use the `var` keyword instead.

Comment: It does support those keywords. I think Tasker supports the ES2015 standard.